# Election comments don't get linked right in "recent activity"

Tags: bug, election

For example, if you were me, you could go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/recent/1189?StartDate=2011-02-18&EndDate=2011-02-18 and see a recent comment by [Martin Tapankov](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/711/martin-tapankov) on [his self-nomination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/election#post-11164) which was addressed to me. But, instead of a link to that post, you would see ... well, nothing. (It just says "commented on ".)

Comment: The first link you included is specific for you. It has your UserID in it. All other users get an 404 *Page not found* error, which is actually a *Permission Denied* in disguise.

Comment: @Martin: I did say "if you were me"; I gave the URL on the theory that Jeff (or another dev) might be permitted to impersonate me in order to reproduce the bug.

Comment: As the election is now over, I've voted-to-close this as "too localised" in order to stop it resurfacing via the community user system.

Comment: @Andrew: you don't think it should instead be migrated to the ur-meta (meta.SO)?

Comment: @SamB: If you can still see the error, then yes, it could be migrated to ur-meta.  The SE team claim that they keep an eye on the per-site metas as well so someone _ought_ to have seen this.  I'm equally happy either way; it's just that the site occasionally brings old discussions to the top again and it's a bit annoying so I like to ensure that questions where that shouldn't happen don't meet the criteria.  One way is by closing them, another is by accepting an answer, or ensuring that an answer has enough votes (don't remember how many).

Comment: @Andrew: Wouldn't migration, which (if I understand things correctly) is treated as a form of closing on the source site, also prevent "community" bumping it here?

Comment: @SamB: Yes it would, and that would be a perfectly acceptable solution.  I do think that you should check that (since the election is over) the bug is still visible before this is migrated (since it's been a while since the bug was first reported).  In fact, I'd recommend making a fresh bug report on the meta site.  You shouldn't think of my vote-to-close as being anything other than a flag saying "this 'question' should be resolved or put to sleep".

Answer (score 3):

It seems that candidates itself do not get notifications for comments below their nomination posts. I at least didn't got one.

---

I got now one for the second comment, but like the OP said, their is no hyper-link or any other reference that this comment is about the nomination page. It just says "commented on" and then nothing.

Comment: I would assume that you received a notification for the second comment because it began with "@Martin", just as I got yours because it began with "@SamB". Perhaps you should report that problem separately?